# Baking - UV's Outside UV Window Don't Bake

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking, scale

I want to bake an unwrapped mesh using a texture image.

It seems that the only part of the mesh being baked is the part inside the UV window.

I can't scale the UV's down because the texture will be too large for the final object.

It's a table made of wood planks - if I scale the UV's down, they're going to look huge.

Can I scale the image instead of the UV's, or is there a setting to allow baking outside the UV window with a repeated texture?

It's an 8k image.

Here's the result of my diffuse bake:

[image]

Comment: *"It seems that the only part of the mesh being baked is the part inside the UV window."* Correct. You can either bake from one UV map to another one where UVs will be packed into 0-1 space or use tileable textures and avoid baking at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale the image inside the Shader editor with the Mapping node, just make this setup:
[image]

Make sure you change X and Y scale together, so you don't stretch your texture one way and not the other.